# Passing multiple parameters in onclick JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

net MVC project with Razor Views. I have implemented a WebGrid and need to pass multiple parameters on an onclick javascript function.
When I am passing one parameter it's working perfectly fine, but upon adding few more parameters it fails to run the script correctly.

My view with WebGrid:

```
      grid.Column(header: "Approve", format: @<text><a onclick="clickAppDisApp(@item.TICKETNUMBER, @item.VISITTYPE, @item.SITEVISITID, 'Approve')" href='javascript:void(0)' class='btnEditSch'>Approve</a></text>),
      grid.Column(header: "Disapprove", format: @<text><a onclick="clickAppDisApp(@item.TICKETNUMBER, @item.VISITTYPE, @item.SITEVISITID, 'Disapprove')" href='javascript:void(0)' class='btnEditSch'>Disapprove</a></text>)
```

Here I'm passing four parameters.
JS Code:

```
      function clickAppDisApp(TICKET, VISITTYPE, SITEVISITID, TYPE) {          
      alert(TICKET + ' ' + VISITTYPE + ' ' + SITEVISITID + ' ' + TYPE + '');
      });
```

I need to take all these parameters to the controller for further action.

Comment: Is `@item.VISITTYPE` a string? You might want to wrap it in single quotes in the markup. Otherwise it would be a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Nisarg it worked!